# Quadratic optimization problem with quadratic equality constraint

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, qcqp

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:

$$
\min_{x \in \mathbf{R}^2} \, x^T A x + b^Tx \quad \text{subject to $x^T J x = 1$}
$$

where $A$ is a positive semi-definite $2 \times 2$ matrix and $J$ is a $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix.
I construct the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L} = x^T A x + b^Tx + \lambda(x^T J x - 1)
$$
from which I obtain the first order condition
$$
2A x + b + 2 \lambda J x = 0
$$
I conclude that the solution must satisfy the expression
$$
x = -\frac{1}{2}(A + \lambda J)^{-1}b
$$
where $\lambda$ solves the equation 
$$
\frac{1}{4}b^T(A + \lambda J)^{-1}J(A + \lambda J)^{-1}b = 1
$$
This equation can be written as a fourth order polynomial in $\lambda$.

My question: How do I know that $A + \lambda J$ is nonsingular at the optimal value of $\lambda$?

Comment: You don't know. $A+\lambda* J$ only needs to be positive semidefinite on the orthogonal complement of $Jx^*$, where $(x^*, \lambda^*)$ satisfies the first order conditions. btw. you mixed $b$ and $g$.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks! Can you help me come up with an example in which $A + \lambda J$ is singular at the optimum?

Comment: minimize $x^T x$ s.t. $x^T x = 1$. Then, the hessian of the Lagrangian is the zero matrix.

Comment: @user251257 Ok then are there conditions guaranteeing that $A + \lambda J$ is nonsingular?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.